I am unable to find the "Open for Editing in Android Studio" option despite having both .iml files in my project
"Open for Editing in android studio" not appearing in the top right corner as usual
option is not appearing in (tools -> flutter)  too
Both .iml files are present in the project
Unable to find its solution, Please assist me with this problem.
